# WinUI3 - keybordaccelerators not working as I expect

Tags: c#, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

I'm creating a opening hours management and I'd like to use `KeyboardAccelerators`.
In my model, I have a save button and I have implemented a save command action when the enter key is pressed in the textbox control.

This is textbox xaml:

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="primaapertura" ex:TextBoxExtensions.Mask="99:99 99:99"
    Margin="0"
    Text="{x:Bind GiorniOperativi.OpeningHours.PrimaApertura, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.KeyboardAccelerators>
        <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Enter" Modifiers="None">
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <interactionCore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Invoked">
                    <interactionCore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind GiorniOperativi.SaveHoursCommand}"/>
                </interactionCore:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </KeyboardAccelerator>
    </TextBox.KeyboardAccelerators>
</TextBox>
```

I've created a gif:
[image]

As you see, it works fine clicking on the save button (first item), while the second doesn't: when I push the enter key it doesn't clear the textbox.
For save new item I use the same method.

**EDIT**

This is my save button:

```
        <Button Command="{x:Bind GiorniOperativi.SaveHoursCommand}" x:Name="salva">
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Save"/>
        </Button>
```

**EDIT 2**

This is SaveOpeningHoursCommand:

```
    [RelayCommand]
    void SaveHours()
    {
        OraAperturaData clone = OpeningHours.CloneObject() as OraAperturaData;

        OraAperturaData isExists= _oc.Where(c => c.IsEqualJson(clone)).FirstOrDefault();
        if(isExists is not null)
        {
            return;
        }
        OraApertura cloneOraApertura=clone.GetOraApertura();
        cloneOraApertura.SecondaApertura = cloneOraApertura.SecondaApertura.Replace("_", string.Empty).Replace(":", string.Empty).Trim();

        OraAperturaData oaExisting = _oc.Where(c => c.GetOraApertura().IsEqualJson(_oldOraApertura)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (_oldOraApertura is not null)
        {
            clone.SetPropertiesValue<OraApertura>(oaExisting);
            
            var isData=ItemsSource.Where(c => c.IsEqualJson(cloneOraApertura)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (isData is not null)
            {
                cloneOraApertura.SetPropertiesValue<OraApertura>(isData);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //OraAperturaData clone = OpeningHours.CloneObject() as OraAperturaData;
            _oc.Add(clone);
            ItemsSource.Add(clone.GetOraApertura().CloneObject() as OraApertura);
        }

        Reset();
    }
```

This Reset method:

```
    [RelayCommand]
    void Reset()
    {
        _oldOraApertura = null;
        //TelefonoInfo = new();
        OpeningHours.Refresh();
    }
```

And this is OpeningHours refresh method:

```
    public void Refresh()
    {
        _ora = new OraApertura();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName: null);
    }
```

**EDIT 3**

A new gif:

[image]

the second textbox not implement keyboardaccelerators

**EDIT 4**

The OpeningHours is the instance of OraAperturaData class as:

```
public partial class OraAperturaData : ObservableObject,IOraApertura
{
    OraApertura _ora;
    public OraAperturaData()
    {
        _ora = new();
    }
    public OraAperturaData(OraApertura apertura)
    {
        _ora = apertura;
    }

    public int? Giorno
    {
        get=>_ora.Giorno;
        set=> SetProperty(_ora.Giorno, value, _ora, (o, p) => { o.Giorno = p; });
    }

    //[CheckHours(ErrorMessage ="Il campo Orario prima apertura non è compilato correttamente")]
    public string PrimaApertura
    {
        get=> _ora.PrimaApertura;
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(_ora.PrimaApertura, value, _ora, (o, p) => o.PrimaApertura = p)) test();
        }
    }

    //[CheckHours(ErrorMessage = "Il campo Orario seconda apertura non è compilato correttamente")]
    public string SecondaApertura
    {
        get => _ora.SecondaApertura;
        set 
        { 
            if (SetProperty(_ora.SecondaApertura, value, _ora, (o, p) => o.SecondaApertura = p)) test(); 
        }
    }

    [ObservableProperty] bool _hasErrors;
    [ObservableProperty] bool _isErrorImgVisible;

    public OraApertura GetOraApertura() => _ora;
    public void Refresh()
    {
        _ora = new OraApertura();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName: null);
    }

    void test()
    {
        if (PrimaApertura is null || SecondaApertura is null)
        {
            HasErrors = true;
            return;
        }
        int primo_=PrimaApertura.Replace("_",string.Empty).Replace(":",string.Empty).Replace(" ",string.Empty).Count();
        int secondo_ = SecondaApertura.Replace("_", string.Empty).Replace(":", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty).Count();

        if (primo_ == 0 && secondo_==0 && Giorno is null)
        {
            HasErrors = true;
            IsErrorImgVisible = false;
            return;
        }

        string pattern = @"(?:[0-1]\d|[2][0-3]):[0-5]\d (?:[0-1]\d|[2][0-3]):[0-5]\d";
        bool regexIsValidPrimaApertura = Regex.IsMatch(PrimaApertura, pattern);
        bool regexIsValidSecondaApertura = Regex.IsMatch(SecondaApertura, pattern);


        if (regexIsValidPrimaApertura && !regexIsValidSecondaApertura && secondo_==0)
        {
            string[] aperturaArray = PrimaApertura.Split(' ');
            DateTime apertura, chiusura;
            DateTime.TryParse(aperturaArray[0], out apertura);
            DateTime.TryParse(aperturaArray[1], out chiusura);

            if (apertura > DateTime.MinValue && chiusura > DateTime.MinValue && chiusura > apertura)
            {
                HasErrors = false;
                IsErrorImgVisible = false;
                //ListaErrori = string.Empty;
                // ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                HasErrors = true;// new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
                IsErrorImgVisible = true;
            }
        }
        else if (!regexIsValidPrimaApertura && regexIsValidSecondaApertura) {HasErrors=true;IsErrorImgVisible = true; }
        else if (!regexIsValidPrimaApertura && !regexIsValidSecondaApertura)
        {
            //if (PrimaApertura.Replace("_",string.Empty).Replace(":",string.Empty).Trim()==string.Empty && SecondaApertura.Replace("_", string.Empty).Replace(":", string.Empty).Trim() == string.Empty)
            //{
                //ListaErrori = string.Empty;
                HasErrors = true;
                IsErrorImgVisible = true;
            //}
        }
        else
        {
            string[] paperturaArray = PrimaApertura.Split(' ');
            string[] saperturaArray=SecondaApertura.Split(' ');
            DateTime papertura, pchiusura,sapertura,schiusura;
            DateTime.TryParse(paperturaArray[0], out papertura);
            DateTime.TryParse(paperturaArray[1], out pchiusura);
            DateTime.TryParse(saperturaArray[0], out sapertura);
            DateTime.TryParse(saperturaArray[1], out schiusura);


            if (papertura > DateTime.MinValue && pchiusura > DateTime.MinValue
                && sapertura > DateTime.MinValue && schiusura > DateTime.MinValue
                && pchiusura > papertura && sapertura > pchiusura && schiusura > sapertura)
            {
                HasErrors = false;
                IsErrorImgVisible = false;
                //ListaErrori = string.Empty;
                // ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                HasErrors = true;// new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
                IsErrorImgVisible= true;
            }
        }

    }     
}
```

The Refresh method of this class create a new _ora instance and I update the properties with "OnPropertyChanged(propertyName:null)" method.

Comment: The second action, the enter-key, does create a new record so the *SaveHoursCommand* is actually called. So your problem is that why the `TextBox` is not cleared right? How are you clearing the `TextBox` when the *Save* button is clicked?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding - It's partially correct. My problem is, why using the same method for adding and clearing data is working in different mode? The button save use SaveHoursCommand too (the first action).

Comment: I've been developing on WinUI 3 for a year now. And "WinUI3 - [...fill in..] not working as I expect" seems to be something I encounter at least once a week

Comment: @JHBonarius Well, let's hope it gets better in the near feature.

Comment: @Kraken Can you post **SaveHoursCommand** method? I'd like to see how you are clearing the `TextBox`.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding I hope so. Some of my colleagues already tried fixing stuff in the repo and opening PRs, but these aren't even looked at. And essential stuff like drag&drop is still broken in some places. We're already 3y into this choice, but are often regretting it. And we're expecting that, like previous Microsoft UI frameworks, they'll just move on to the next new thing instead of fixing this.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding I note that not working for the communitytoolkit extension. If I remove ex:TextBoxExtensions.Mask="99:99 99:99", it work fine

Comment: I actually created a small test app with the **TextExtensions.Mask** and works as expected.

Comment: The `TextBox.Text` is bound to **PrimaApertura** but I don't see a code that clears that.

Comment: Have you tried a simple PrimaApertura = string.Empty?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding The refresh method in concrete class of OpeningHours re-initialize the instance class. EDIT 4

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding As your indication, I added ti SaveHours method, as last, **OpeningHours.PrimaApertura=string.Empty**, but nothing.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding I noted that if I click on X button in textbox control, it remove only last character. I tested on new project with only a stackpanel, a textbox and listbox